# Passing an array in Python to Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Let's say that I had an array in the Python backend and wanted to pass it to the front end as json or a js array. How would I be able to do this using the Django framework?

This is what the template might look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var array = {{djangoVariable}};
//use the array somehow
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full view so you get the idea:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core import serializers

def my_view(request) :
    json_data = serializers.serialize('json', my_django_object)
    render_to_response('my_template.html', {'json_data' : json_data})
```

Comment: +1 for using django's serializers. They are really useful. I should use them more.

Comment: haha I've actually never used them before. I just did a cursory search of the django docs for "json encode". I figured django probably had a fancy way of doing things.

Comment: I remember learning about them when I first studied about django. But since them I always used simplejson or even 'str' for that kind of need.

Comment: I'm just begining with Python / Django. Is there a benefit to simplejson over serializers? performance / correctness? Or do you use simplejson out of habit?

Comment: Django's serializers **only** work for querysets. Any other type of data, and you need to use simplejson directly.

Comment: Daniel is right. About the performance, django uses a bundled version of simplejson, so there are no benefits of using simplejson directly.

Answer (score 3):

I try the answer, but the think that work by me was like:

in the view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.utils import simplejson


def example_view(request):
   variable = {"myvar":[1, 2, 3]}
   render_to_response("example.html", simplejson.dumps(variable),
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in the example.html

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myvar = "{{ myvar|safe }}";
</script>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Django:**
from django.utils import simplejson
json = simplejson.dumps(YOUR_VARIABLE)

AND PASS "json" IN CONTEXT

**IN JS:**
var YOUR_JS_OBJECT = {{json|safe}};

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read a django tutorial on how to pass variables from python to the template.

BUT

If your python list is a list of numbers, you could just use `str` or the module simplejson on it that it would be already a javascript array to use in your template.

For example:

in your views.py:

```
import simplejson
def example_view(request)
   variable = [1, 2, 3]
   return render(request, 'example.html', {'djangoVariable': simplejson.dumps(variable)})
```

Comment: In fact in python 2.6+, the standard module json is exactly the same as simple json

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
js_variable = simplejson.dumps(django_variable)
```

and pass `js_variable` to your template in the normal way.

Comment: I have tried it but " is translated to &quot; :  [&quot;microones&quot;, &quot;normal&quot;, &quot;large&quot;, &quot;xl&quot;]  instead ["microones", ...